# Fetch YouTube Video Id from youtube URL in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is my youtube tube URL which is coming from facebook Id. I have fetch this url using FQL Query in facebook in Zend Framework

This is my url = "http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=AbE6fYtNaa4&u=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DNbyHNASFi6U%26feature%3Dshare"

Now I need to fetch its ID so that I can pass it to this code so that i can generate its vidoe details.

```
function listYoutubeVideo($id) {
    $video = array();

    try {   
        $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();

        $videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry($id);



        $videoEntry = $yt->getQueryUrl($id);


            $videoThumbnails = $videoEntry->getVideoThumbnails();
            $video = array(
                'thumbnail' => $videoThumbnails[0]['url'],
                'title' => $videoEntry->getVideoTitle(),
                'description' => $videoEntry->getVideoDescription(),
                'tags' => implode(', ', $videoEntry->getVideoTags()),
                'url' => $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl(),
                'flash' => $videoEntry->getFlashPlayerUrl(),
                'dura' => $videoEntry->getVideoDuration(),
                'id' => $videoEntry->getVideoId()
            );

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();

    }


    return $video;
}
```

So I just need to find its youtube ID from youtube URL in Zend Framework. Plz provide me solutions. Is there any method exist in `"Zend_Gdata_YouTube"` class from where i can get its ID form passing its youtube URL

Comment: Excuse me if this sounds stupid, but isn't the video id in the url? Isn't it simply the `v` paramater? You could extract that from the url right?

Comment: Yes, I know that youtube ID exist after V parameter. Basically i am getting this youtube url from facebook's user profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unique video ID. In your case (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbyHNASFi6U&feature=share) ID equals  **NbyHNASFi6U**.

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=AbE6fYtNaa4&u=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DNbyHNASFi6U%26feature%3Dshare';
$url = urldecode($url);
$query_string = end(explode('?',$url));
parse_str($query_string);
$videoID = $v;
print $videoID;
// OUTPUT
NbyHNASFi6U
```

> The video watch page URL always has this format:
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX
>
> where XXXXXXXXXXX is a unique video ID consisting of 11 letters and numbers (and, if memory serves, hyphens and underscores).

Comment: Yes, I know that youtube ID exist after V parameter. Basically i am getting this youtube url from facebook's user profile.So can you suggest me how to get Id from this url through Youtube API or something else

Comment: @Omega I update answer (for your example url). Now you can pass varialbe `$VideoID` into function `listYoutubeVideo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_id($url)
{
    $ytshorturl = 'youtu.be/';
    $ytlongurl = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
    if (strpos($url, $ytshorturl) !== false) {
        $url = str_replace($ytshorturl, $ytlongurl, $url);
    }
    $components = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($components['query'], $results);
    return $results['v'];
}

$url = "https://youtu.be/oeg192rQ1xE"; //sample url

print(get_id($url));
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: I have added function calling with url please check.

Comment: I have edited your answer to make sure that the added code appears as code. I do understand your solution, but novices will not understanding. This is why you need to explain your solution with words, so even the less experienced will understand it.